# Unify 10^x power in a sequence of number

Tags: java, scientific-notation

I have a sequence of numbers like this:

```
1.687155E21
3.981457E19
0.5532155E21 
3.018843E21
2.0532155E21 
4.5532155E21
3.1637913E19
```

My problem is how to convert the two numbers which ends with 10^19 to be like the others (10^21). Because after this unification i need to trunc the number to print only something like 3.5.

In C/C++ i know how to work with precision, but in Java I haven't got any idea.

Comment: Do you want to take a bunch of `double`s and convert them to strings such that they all have the form `<int>.<fraction>E<exponent>` where the exponent is the minimum of the one-int-digit exponent for all non-zero values?

Comment: No. Yes, at the end i need to transform into string but only with one decimal.

Comment: Most of the same functions available in C/C++ are available in Java though the names may have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest something similar as Tomasz Nurkiewicz did, but instead of dividing by `1E19` divide by `1E21`, convert them to strings with the required precision using Formatter (see the comment of count0) but not as scientific format, but as a general one. In the end just add E21 to those strings. In the end you should get (I hope, I got the idea correctly)

```
1.687155E21
0.03981457E21
0.5532155E21 
3.018843E21
2.0532155E21 
4.5532155E21
0.031637913E21
```

Comment: That's the easy solution. Thanks. That's works fine in this case. But I would want to know how to know the Exx of a number to know an strategy to follow in any future situation.

Comment: The answer is easy and somewhat mathematical. Just compute the decadic logarithm (`Math.log10()`) and take the integer part of it. You will get the magnitude `Exx`.

Comment: Thanks Vic, great answer another time.

Answer (score 2):

Divide all your number by `/ 1e19`, round to as many decimal digits you want:

```
168.7155
3.981457
55.32155
301.8843
205.32155
455.32155
3.1637913
```

Comment: How can I round with the decimal digits that i want ??? I think I need to divide into / 1e21 because the numbers with e19 must be 0 or 0.x

Answer (score 2):

Use the Formatter Class to bring them into the desired scientific notation ([java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html))

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just multiply the `E19` numbers by `10 ^ 2 = 100`?

After they have been normalized to `E21`, you should be able to divide all of them by `10^21` (if they're floats), and they will all be in the range of 0-9.999...

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is to detect if the numbers is E19 o E21, I don't know how to do that.